# Density of $\mathcal{C}_c(A\times B)$ in $L^p(A, L^q(B))$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $A, B$ be two open sets in  $\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m$ respectively and denote $\mathcal{C}_c(A\times B)$ the  space of continuous functions with compact support in $A\times B.$

Is $\mathcal{C}_c(A\times B)$ dense in $L^p(A, L^q(B))$ for any $+\infty > q,p \geq 1 ?$

I believe that the answer is **YES** and I'm looking for a simple proof. It is well known that  $\mathcal{C}_c(A\times B)$ is dense in $L^r(A\times B)$ 
for any $r\geq 1.$ Does this help?

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: How would you define $L^p(A, L^q(B))$?

Comment: the set of functions $f : A\times B \to \mathbb{R},$ where for a.e $x\in A,$  $f(x,.) \in L^q(B)$  and $x\mapsto \|f(x,.)\|_{L^q(B)} \in L^p(A).$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more general statement. Suppose $V\subset L^p(A)$ and $W\subset L^q(B)$ are dense subspaces. Define $V\otimes W$ to be their algebraic tensor product, that is the linear span of functions $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for $f\in V$, $g\in W$.

**Theorem**: $V\otimes W$ is dense in $L^p(A, L^q(B))$  provided $p,q\in [1,\infty)$.

To apply this theorem to your case, let $V$ and $W$ be spaces of continuous functions with compact support; then $V\otimes W\subset C_c(A\times B)$.

*Proof of the theorem*: Recall that a function $\phi\in L^p(A,L^q(B))$ is simple if there is a partition of $A$ into $A_1,\dots,A_N$ such that 
$$
\phi = \sum_{k=1}^N \chi_{A_k} g_k\quad \text{for some } g_k\in L^q(B) \tag1
$$
Consider $f\in L^p(A,L^q(B))$. Since $f$ is Bochner measurable, there exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of simple functions that converges to $f$ pointwise. Using the density of $W$, we may arrange so that the constituent functions $g_k$ in (1) are from $W$.

Consider the sets
$$E_n = \{x \in A : \|f_n(x)\|_{L^q} \le 2\|f(x)\|_{L^q}\}$$
Sine $\|f_n(\cdot)\|_{L^q} \to \|f(\cdot)\|_{L^q}$ pointwise, each point of $x$ where $f(x)\ne 0$ is eventually in $E_n$. Hence,  letting 
$$
h_n = f_n \chi_{E_n}
$$
we still have $h_n\to f$ pointwise. But now 
$$
\|h_n(x)-f(x)\|_{L^q}\le \|h_n(x)\|_{L^q}+ \|f(x)\|_{L^q} \le 3\|f(x)\|_{L^q}
$$
so by the dominated convergence theorem $h_n\to f$ in $L^p(A,L^q(B))$.

So far we have shown that functions of the form 
$$
\phi = \sum_{k=1}^N \chi_{A_k} g_k\quad \text{for some } g_k\in W \tag2
$$
are dense in $L^p(A,L^q(B))$. But each such $\phi$ can be approximated by elements of $V\otimes W$ by picking a sequence from $V$ that converges to $\chi_{A_k}$ in $L^p(A)$. $\quad\Box$

The above is essentially Proposition 1.2 on page 2 of the book [Martingales in Banach spaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=n3JNDAAAQBAJ) by Pisier, an early draft of which can be found on [author's page](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gilles.pisier/ihp-pisier.pdf).

Comment: Funny. I realized today that $C_c^\infty(A) \otimes C_c^\infty(B)$ probably is dense, and now, back at my computer, I went to this question to make a comment about it. And then I saw this answer using the same idea.

Comment: Good Poof.. I was really thinking that I should separate the variables (implicitly the functions $F(x,y) = f(x)g(y).$) We might write an article :D